# Transaction reverted

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle, openzeppelin

I am a beginner in writing smart contract. I want to deploy a crowdsale and token contract on the Kovan testnet. Everything works well except when I tried to send KTH to the crowdsale contract. I always get "reverted transaction" in the end. Could someone help me solve this situation? I am using the standard Crowdsale and Token sale contract from openZeppelin and truffle suite.

Crowdsale contract: https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x68321f1380ac45be3f3d85d0cd95d1ac5710b8a9#code

Token contract: 
https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0xb76b6ae76cee43e0b32588ffc112efca3c781f1e#code

Comment: If your transaction is being reverted, it could be that you are exceeding the gas limit. The gas limit for Kovan is about 8000000. See https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27452/how-to-estimate-gas-cost for an explanation on how to estimate the gas used by your transaction.

Comment: Thanks. I just checked the gas used to proceed this transaction. it is actually 7592571 not exceeding the gas limit.